# LoggerFactory - output location

Tags: java, logging, hadoop

When running Hadoop through Java code, where does the output of a LoggerFactory object usage go? How to trace this logger?

Answer (score 0):

If your LoggerFactory object is part of slf4j api, you should have either a xml or properties configuration file in your classpath. If it is present, you should be able to read the log file path.